# delegate to Storyboard created View Controller

Tags: swift, xcode, delegates, viewcontroller

i created two projects to learn how the delegate method is working..
one project created WITHOUT storyboard, just via code and my delegate is working just fine.

i built the other Project WITH storyboard, which means all ViewControllers are visible in the Interfacebuilder..

i am sure the issue lays in the definition of the ViewControllers in the code file:

```
let homeVC = HomeViewController()
```

Can someone please tell what is wrong here?

```
import UIKit


protocol HomeViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func showMenu()
}


class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var delegate: HomeViewControllerDelegate?
   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    title = "App"
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureNaviBar()
        
    }
    
    func configureNaviBar() {

        // Left Bar Button Item
        let burgerButton = UIImage(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: burgerButton, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(showMenu))
    }
    
    @objc func showMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("show Menu (home)")
        // homeDelegate is nil?
        
        delegate!.showMenu()    // throws an error!
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let naviVC:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NaviVC") as! NaviVC
    let menuVC:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideMenuID") as! SideMenuViewController
    let homeVC = HomeViewController()
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        setupContainerView()
    }
        
    func setupContainerView() {
        // menu
        addChild(menuVC)
        self.view.addSubview(menuVC.view)
        menuVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 896)
        menuVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        // Home
        homeVC.delegate = self
        addChild(naviVC)
        self.view.addSubview(naviVC.view)
        naviVC.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        naviVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}


extension MainViewController: HomeViewControllerDelegate {
    func showMenu() {
        // does not get called
        print("did tap menu")
    }
}
```

Error:
Debug_project/HomeViewController.swift:49: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

i am already searching for days now, and just can't find the solution for this...
please help me out guys

Comment: Exactly: `HomeViewController()` is wrong, it creates a new instance which is not the instance in the storyboard. You need the actual reference like in the two lines above.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write a reply - THX! but unfortunately I tried that multiple times..if I do so, then Xcode is immediately telling me: "Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'delegate'"

Comment: You have to `instantiate` the controller and cast it to `HomeViewController`.

Comment: as said above, I tried that so many times.. Xcode tells me at the line number where I got: "homeVC.delegate = self" that my HomeVC does not have a delegate.. "Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'delegate'"

Comment: If you get *"Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'delegate'"* then you didn't cast the type (`instantiateViewController(with...) as! HomeViewController`)

Comment: ty vadian your help is really appreciated! I declared that HomeVC like that: "let homeVC:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController"

Comment: Delete `:UIViewController` (also in the other lines). Don't annotate (wrong) types the compiler can infer.

Comment: ok! I get what u mean, I deleted that:UIViewController and the error message now appears  at runtime as soon as I tap that UIBarButtonItem: "Debug_project/HomeViewController.swift:49: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"..what is wrong here? I am thinking about deleting that project and build it again from scratch.. no ideas left any more :(

Comment: You missed an underscore plus space character `@objc func showMenu(_ sender: AnyObject)`. And as the sender is something specific better write `@objc func showMenu(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)`

Comment: damnit :( you're right! but this doesn't solve it neither :( the delegate is still nil

Comment: Have you told the storyboard that the controller's class is `HomeViewController`.  That's usually what's missing when the errors say there's a problem with a member variable in a `UIViewController`.

Comment: thank you Phillip, I double checked that to be sure, and yes: the SB View Controller is connected to the correct swift file..and there is also the Storyboard ID: "HomeViewController" ..I just don't get it, what's wrong here?

Comment: i re-wrote the project from scratch and the same is happening again :( delegate is nil again -.-

Comment: So how and where are you instantiating `homeVC` now?  Also, I don't see where `homeVC` ever gets presented.  (I'm now wondering whether you're using 2 different HomeViewController instances, setting the delegate in one and getting the error from another.)

Comment: I'm instantiating homeVC in the Container View Controller like this: let homeVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController  ...and the Storyboard ID is set to "HomeViewController" ..I am pretty much following this guide here, except that I cannot just do it via code, I have to use storyboard : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1hzPFAYcuUI&t=532s

Comment: I suspect that your storyboard is set up in some way that creates and shows a HomeViewController automatically...and it's not `homeVC`.  Can you print a couple of things to confirm whether I'm on the right track?  Print the value of `homeVC` when you assign the delegate and the value of `self` just before the error.  (Another thing to try is connecting the MainViewController to the delegate outlet **inside the storyboard**.  Since I can't see your project, I can't be sure if that will or won't work.)

Comment: I built a complete new project from scratch, and focused just on the necessary parts for testing this issue, so in SB I just connected .swift file with the View Controller, and set StoryboardID..that's it... after assignment homeVC: 0x00000001367089c0  ...before delegate function call: 0x000000012160b580  ...so those are indeed different..wtf?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241441/discussion-between-phillip-mills-and-blendstylez).

Comment: One more question before I admit defeat.  Is there a HomeViewController being loaded along with the NaviVC?  (In other words, embedded in the nav.)

Comment: that'S a good idea...HomeViewController in Storyboard is the rootVielController for NavVC, yes...I could try to remove that Nav, and try again...I'll do that (y)

Comment: What probably works best is to not create a `HomeViewController` in code but to get the one that's owned by the nav controller and set **its** delegate.

Comment: alright, I thought like: NaviVC.viewControllers.first.delegate = self but that does not work..

Comment: . so I tried to build that WITHOUT a navi, and it is working now! so the homeVC attached to the naviVC is indeed the problem..but how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!
Tanks to Phillip Mills and all others for helping me find this..
the solution is:

change

```
let homeVC = HomeViewController()
```

to

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
let homeVC = naviVC.viewControllers.first as! HomeViewController    // working: this is it!
}
```

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let naviVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NaviVC") as! NaviVC
    let menuVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideMenuID") as! SideMenuViewController


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        setupContainerView()
    }
        
    func setupContainerView() {
        // menu
        addChild(menuVC)
        self.view.addSubview(menuVC.view)
        menuVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 896)
        menuVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        // Home
        let homeVC = naviVC.viewControllers.first as! HomeViewController    // working: this is it!
        homeVC.delegate = self
        addChild(naviVC)
        self.view.addSubview(naviVC.view)
        naviVC.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        naviVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}


extension MainViewController: HomeViewControllerDelegate {
    func showMenu() {
        // does not get called
        print("did tap menu")
    }
}
```